# Old movie about a lavish woman clashing with a town doctor

Tags: identify-this-movie

I don't know who the actor is, it could be Cary Grant or some one like him but around that time frame of actors.
The actress is not one I know so much about.

- He is a doctor in a small American country town out fishing. She
  turns up and rings the bell.
- There is lots of fighting between the doctor and her in a funny way.
- She buys things for the town's people with them knowing it is coming
  from her.
- She was sick as a child and town sent her away to get fixed and this
  why she is buying stuff.
- Towards the end of the movie hundreds people from all of America come
  to this town to get free money which causes major problems for the
  town.
- The doctor gets up to speaks to these strangers before a war almost
  happens and the people leave the town.
- The doctor and girl do fall in love with each other.

Comment: "She buys things for the town's people with them knowing it is coming from her" - I wonder if you mean "without them knowing"?

Comment: @Fruitbat Yeah, what I assumed too.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're after [She Couldn't Say No](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047476/combined) from 1954.

> heiress Corby Lane (Jean Simmons) [comes] to a small Arkansas town to play Santa Claus because, when she was a small child traveling with her impoverished father, the townspeople saved her life by donating money needed for [her] medical treatment. She meets and falls in love with "Doc" Sellers (Robert Mitchum), an easy-going doctor who enjoys fishing and the unhurried pace of the town. Corby's gesture of handing out money and lavish gifts to the citizens backfires when, after it has been publicized, the town becomes the destination of every wayward traveler and fortune seeker.

It was later released as *Beautiful But Dangerous* in the UK. Here's the trailer: